# Selecting between Zabbix Agent, SNMP and other available protocols in Zabbix NMS

Tags: linux, network-monitoring, snmp, zabbix

I have started using zabbix 3.2 and currently I am monitoring 10 devices , 8 of which are Snmp based and 2 are Agent based. Currently both type of devices are showing basic data like CPU, Memory etc. Performance wise I do not see much difference now but I would like to know which is better SNMP or Agent based monitoring.

If in near future I am monitoring 1000's of devices i.e servers which would be better SNMP or Agent and why?

I do realize both have there own pros and cons, so how should I decide while selecting between Agent and SNMP. Can anyone please guide me ?
I tried searching in previous threads but didn't get any good information.

Answer (score 0):

> Reasons to use SNMP agents instead of Zabbix agents might include already installed and set up SNMP agents, no access to monitored hosts to install Zabbix agents, and desire to keep systems relatively free from dependencies on monitoring software.

Reference: https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/networking_and_servers/9781847197689/4